# Convert AQL query to Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, arangodb, tinkerpop, aql

I'm doing a project relate to [graph databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases), and I'm using [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/) to create graph and try some queries with that. I have 2 JSON files below and I have already [imported them into ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/administration-import-export.html) and created graph

```js
( airports : document collection, flights : edge collection)
```

I have 2 examples of AQL queries for the graph, but I'm struggling with converting them to Gremlin queries.

```js
    ex1 ( flights that leave JFK airport): 
            FOR v,e,p IN 1..1 OUTBOUND
           'airport/JFK'
           GRAPH 'flights'
           RETURN p
    
    ex2 ( flights from SF to KOA international airport and have VIP lounges):
           FOR airport IN airports
           FILTER airport.city == "San Francisco"
           FILTER airport.VIP == true
           FOR v,e,p IN 1..1 OUTBOUND
           airport flights
           FILTER v._id == 'airports/KOA'
           RETURN p
```

Can you help me with this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may [find the examples here](http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html) of interest as they are specific to Gremlin and air route use cases. Without having your data model or some sample data it is not possible to give you a 100% accurate translation of your queries. However, the Gremlin will look something like this:

```js
    // FLights that leave JFK airport
    g.V().has('airport','code','JFK').
      out().
      path()

    // Flights from SFO to KOA that have a VIP lounge
    g.V().has('airport','city','San Francisco').
      has('VIP','true').
      out().
      has('code','KOA').
      path()
```

Comment: Hi , thank you so much , how can i give you the json files so that you can translate easier?

Comment: It would be helpful if your question included the data model of your graph. What Gremlin have you tried so far?

Comment: i use all the sources of this course https://www.udemy.com/course/getting-started-with-arangodb/learn/lecture/15078990#overview , including the dataset . Can you help me to convert AQL queries into gremlin queries ?

Comment: Unfortunately that site requires an account. If you want people to help you on Stack Overflow you will need to provide some sort of generic example that represents the data model you are working with. You may want to review these guidelines:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  What have you tried so far? In my answer above I gave you the basic framework for the type of queries you will need to write and the link to an in-depth Gremlin tutorial that works with a very similar data set to yours.